# How to add a fluorescent effect on an image in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders

I have recently been attempting to create a true on-screen representation of a fluorescent orange colour on an image. Whereby, I believe post-processing with unity will deliver the best results.

Thus, I was wondering if someone could kindly guide me through the steps to add a fluorescent effect to my image?

As a reference I would like to try match pantone 804c on screen.

**Image in question:**
[image: The current image]

I have tried to follow tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnG2gOKV9dw), but unfortunately they all are working on 3D scenes. I have a pre-existing jpg image that I want to modify.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make it give the illusion that it produced light? I'm not sure I understand what the desired result is from the picture

Comment: Yeah kind of, the orange currently looks too dull and not fluorescent at all. I think using Shader Graph if you assign the shader an emission value. You can set & expose a vector 1 for the emission strength and set & expose a colour input for the emission as well as for diffuse and then you can live-adjust those in the Editor. Unfortunately, I am new to unity and wouldn't know how to do this

Comment: I've seen many tutorials online how to create glow in Unity, have you tried any?

Comment: @TomTsagk I have checked out a couple but none that are very "noob" friendly.

Comment: It would be easier if in your question you mentioned what tutorial you've found and where you got stuck. The last thing you'd want is yet another person giving you an answer which is similar to something you've already tried.

Comment: @TomTsagk I have update with example of one video.

Comment: Possibly the wrong software to use?! I think you could achieve that in photoshop, just search for ```photoshop fluorescent effect```